# One-dimensional submodules of $\mathbb{C}^4$; direct sum of submodules.

Tags: modules, representation-theory, direct-sum

I'm having some trouble understanding my lecture notes.

I need to find a one-dimensional submodule $U$ of $\mathbb{C}^4$.

Is $u=1+x+x^2+x^3$ valid? My reasoning: because $ux = x + x^2 + x^3 + 1 = u \in U$. Would, say, $1+ix-x^2-ix^3$ be a different one?

I also have to express $\mathbb{C}^4$ as a direct sum of $\mathbb{C}G$-submodules ($G$ = <$x, y | x^4 = y^2=1, yxy=x^{-1}$>). Two of them have to be one-dimensional - does this mean the third must be two-dimensional? How do I do the direct sum of different dimensional things? I know this must seem like a very easy question but I really can't find a good explanation of 'direct sum' *anywhere*!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is not enough information here. What is $G$? How does it act on $\mathbb{C}^4$?

Comment: $G \cong D_8 = <x, y|x^4 = y^2 = 1, yxy=x^{-1}>$. I also have the representation $\rho$ given by $x\rho =  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} , y \rho =  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.$